# Crashlytics Android SDK warning message from googleplay (com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.3.0)

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

After publishing the app I got the following error in Play Console.

[image]

For the solution, it is said that it is necessary to choose a version above the "implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.3.0' version, for example 18.3.1, but I had never added it anyway.

[image]

Would it be enough to upgrade firebase packages in package.json to solve this problem? Or what else should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason you don't see the implementations on the React Native side is because adding implementations should be handled under the hood by the package you added in package.json.
So in theory updating it should be enough.

However since this is Firebase update also all firebase packages to an equivalent version